# Converting ROOT Tree to HDF5

Tags: hdf5, h5py, root-framework, rootpy

I have a TTree in ROOT with 1000 events and 15 variables associated to each of them. I would like to convert this in its entirety to an hdf5 dataset. How do I organise my data in HDF5 Groups such that I can access data both by event number and by variable (if I wanted all the data from the 'kinetic energy' variable for example, over all events)? Note: I have already tried the root2hdf5 conversion tool but this does not work for branches with arrays / compound datatypes.

Answer (score 0):

You can try loading the TTree into a Pandas Dataframe with [root_pandas](https://github.com/scikit-hep/root_pandas), which should work for array branches (not sure for compound datatypes).
From there, you can use both event and variable indexing, and use the regular Pandas functionality to save in your favorite format like HDF5.